# Отправка email письма ошибка php

Tags: php, html

Пишет что-то пошло не так где ошибка?

```
<form method="post" action="">

<input type="text" name="to" placeholder="Enter email">

<br><br>

<input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Enter the title of the letter">

<br><br>

<textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Enter the text of the letter" rows="5"></textarea>

<br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send"><br><br>

</form>

<br><br>

 

<?php

$headers =  'From: no-reply@example.com' . "\r\n" .

            'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .

            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (isset($_POST['to']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message']))

    if (mail($_POST['to'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], $headers)) {

        echo '<font color=green><b>письмо было принято для передачи</b></font>';

    } else {

        echo '<font color=red><b>что-то пошло не так...</b></font>';

    }

?>
```